# Eclipse+Pydev: "cleanup" functions aren't called when pressing "stop""?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, del

Trying to run this file in eclipse

```
class Try:
   def __init__(self):
       pass
   def __del__(self):
       print 1
a=Try()
raw_input('waiting to finish')
```

and pressing the stop button without letting the program finish doesn't print "1", i.e the del method is never called. If i try to run the script from the shell and do ctrl-c\sys.exit "1" does get printed i.e del is called.
Same thing if I try to use wait():

```
class A:

    def __enter__(self):
        return None
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        print 3


with A():
    print 1
    raw_input('Waiting')
    print 2
```

If i press "stop" when prompted, "3" isn't printed

Why is that?
Is there a way around it?

Thanks, Noam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pressing stop in Eclipse outright kills the interpreter (though it actually fails fairly often).  Like using `kill`/`taskkill`, the process is unaware of it's demise.

[Ctrl+C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-C) snippet from Wikipedia...

> Control-C as an abort command was
>   popularized by UNIX and adopted in
>   other systems. In POSIX systems, the
>   sequence causes the active program to
>   receive a SIGINT signal. If the
>   program does not specify how to handle
>   this condition, it is terminated.
>   Typically a program which does handle
>   a SIGINT will still terminate itself,
>   or at least terminate the task running
>   inside it.

`Ctrl+C` is a control signal to interrupt the program, but as you may have noticed in the middle of that paragraph, programs can specify how to handle the signal.  In Python, Ctrl+C [throws a KeyboardInterrupt exception](http://effbot.org/zone/stupid-exceptions-keyboardinterrupt.htm) which is normally caught and then Python exits cleanly.  Even if you're killing the interpreter with `Ctrl+C` it may handle it so that it cleans the environment before exiting.

I included the following because you asked "Is there a way around it?"

If you are wanting to stop on `raw_input(...)` calls, you could use `Ctrl+Z` to send EOF.  I looked around, and there seems to be no way to send `Ctrl+C`/`0x03` in Eclipse, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, but I think you didn't answer my question - when running from the shell, stopping the *interpreter* with ctrl-c still calls __del__, but when stopping it in eclipse that doesn't happen. 
I am not looking for a solution, just wondering what's causing the difference

Comment: I was a bit off, or at least explained poorly, so I cleaned it up a bit and added a more info.

Comment: OK, thanks - Your answer is spot on. I didn't understand it at first. Sorry

Answer (score 4):

Python docs:

> ```
> __del__(self)
> ```
>
> Called when the instance is about to be destroyed. This is also called a destructor. If a base class has a `__del__()` method, the derived class's `__del__()` method, if any, must explicitly call it to ensure proper deletion of the base class part of the instance. Note that it is possible (though not recommended!) for the `__del__()` method to postpone destruction of the instance by creating a new reference to it. It may then be called at a later time when this new reference is deleted. **It is not guaranteed that `__del__()` methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits.**

If you want to guarantee that a method is called use the [with-statement](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, But I am not sure this is the right thing for my case:
I have class A, that holds an instance of class B, and B holds some external resource it must explicitly release on exit.
How can i solve this issue using with? make explicit methods called close() both for A and B ?

Comment: Moreover, wait() doesn't work any better than delete in eclipse - try to press stop and you'll see that __exit__ isn't called...